# Transcendence base of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinitely many elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I need to show that transcendence base of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinitely many elements. Since I do not know much about ordinals and cardinals, a proof based on algebra (rather than comparing cardinality) would be helpful.

Explicitly, I would like to prove that $\mathbb{C}$ cannot be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ where $\lbrace x_i \rbrace$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It is elementary considerations around cardinals that are required and nothing sophisticated. I look for an algebraic proof

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{C}$ is uncountable while $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is countable $\forall n$. As I said in my comment I look for a different proof that is more "algebraic"

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is countable. (there is a surjection from $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)[T]\times\mathbb N$ onto $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}$)